# How to write to a Python console using Python

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, console, micropython

there is a device that runs uPython (Micropython) which is connected to my computer via a serial connection. When I open a console on COM19, e.g. with Moba XTerm I can execute uPython commands, e.g. `2+3`:

[image]

The point is, I want to execute scripts instead of developing them "live" in the console. So I figured I write a Python script which writes to the serial console automatically:

```
import serial
import time

# config
baud = 115200
port = "COM19"
TOUT = 1


def main():
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=TOUT)
    time.sleep(2)

    # Read a few lines to "read away" the header if existing
    ser.readline()
    ser.readline()
    ser.readline()

    # the problem is here I guess - the newline character does not trigger
    # the execution of the command - how can I encode the "Enter" keypress? 
    ser.write(str.encode("2+3\n"))
    time.sleep(2)

    # I would expect it to read "5"
    output_line = ser.readline()
    print(output_line.decode('utf8'))

    ser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think the problem is that the newline charakter does not trigger the same behaviour as the enter-keypress in the terminal does (see comment in the code). The question is, how can I "activate" the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `Enter` will send a newline (`CR` + `LF`). So you have to send `\n\r` at the end of your message.

Comment: I was just going to comment my question - you are right that is what it does. I'll leave the question here just in case someone has the same problem.

Comment: A better solution should be to use `os` and `os.linesep`. This will result in a plattform independend solution, because Linux doesn´t use `\n\r` :). Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-click method to upload a Python script from your PC to your Micropython device and run it there, there are IDEs and other tools that have this capability - for example [Thonny](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/wiki/MicroPython), [uPyCraft](https://github.com/DFRobot/uPyCraft) and others discussed on [this forum thread](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5454).

I don't know which of these will or will not work on your particular board but the Micropython forum would be the best place to ask.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it